# adding inline CSS in datatable row on condition not working

Tags: php

I tried to highlight records whose certain columns have some values other than NULL. I'm using dataTable plugin.

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="checkin-checkout-record-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Check-in-date</th>
        <th>Check-in-time</th>
        <th>Check-out-date</th>
        <th>Check-out-time</th>
        <th class="col-lg-2">Late Check-in Remarks</th>
        <th class="col-lg-2">Early Check-out Remarks</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
  <tbody>

        <?php
        foreach ($checkinCheckoutList as $member): ?>
        <tr <?php
       if(isset($member['early_checkout_remarks']) ||isset($member['delayed_checkin_remarks']))
        {?>
        style="background-color:red;"
        <?php } ?> >
        <td><?php echo $member['fullname'] ?></td> 
        <td> <?php echo $member['checkin_date']; ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $member['checkin_time']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $member['checkout_date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $member['checkout_time']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $member['delayed_checkin_remarks']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $member['early_checkout_remarks']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
```

But the result is not as expected. Some records are not highlighted. This works well with other normal table. Please help.

Comment: Give us sample data. Which column is meant to be NULL ?

Comment: Do you mean that some rows do have a check-in or check-out remark, yet they are not colored red? Please be very specific, no other columns should be involved. Any pattern you can see in the rows that are not red?

Comment: yes .. there are some records with either of those columns set, and yet they are not highlighted. I wish I could share screenshot with you guys.

Comment: I tried adding other style "color:white" and it is working fine. Only the background-style is not working according to the condition expression.

Comment: This probably would help you guys - http://jsfiddle.net/2chjxduy/ or this one http://jsfiddle.net/GfNeA/